# How to hide tr that has all td's that are alert-success?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

So I want to hide `tr` that has td's where if only all `tds` have class `alert-success` then only hide `tr` otherwise show `tr`.

I tried:

```
$('tr:has(td.alert-success)').css('display', 'none');
```

But this hides tr even if one td has class `alert-success` even if there are tds with class `alert-danger`.

How should I solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to loop throught all the `tr` and compare the amount of `td` versus the amount of `td.alert-success`.

The comparison is then made row by row.

```
$("tr").each(function(){
  var successTds = $(this).find("td.alert-success").length;
  var dangerTds = $(this).find("td.alert-dager").length;
  var allTds = $(this).find("td").length;

  if (successTds + dangerTds === allTds) {
    $(this).hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: Sorry but a small problem is that I have many other tds in the row so I must have the count of only tds that have either alert-success or alert-danger in the all TDS variable. How can I achieve that ?

Comment: Okay, you can count the `.alert-danger` too... I edited.